# Limit is ignored when remove (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to remove the earliest several documents in a collection, so I wrote something like this:

```
Model.remove({
    u: "abc"
}).sort({
    _id: 1
}).limit(10).exec(function (err, count) {
    // count gives the total documents number...
});
```

And this:

```
Model.find(...).sort(...).limit(...).remove(...);
```

Hoping someone would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MongoDB's remove operation doesn't support a limit option, but you can `find` the `_id`s of the docs you want to remove, and then use `$in` to remove them:

```
Model.find({u: "abc"}).select('_id').sort({_id: 1}).limit(10)
    .exec((err, docs)=> {
        const ids = docs.map((doc)=> doc._id);
        Model.deleteMany({_id: {$in: ids}}, (err)=> {...}); 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`db.collection.remove()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) doesn't return a cursor.  So, you cannot append [cursor methods](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/) like sort() or limit(), like you can to a [`db.collection.find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) operation.

You might want to look at [`db.collection.findAndModify()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/), to which you can supply a `remove` parameter to delete a document.

Comment: sorry, actually i meant model there (modified). will this do the same?