# How to pass limit to Mongoose db.collection.deleteMany

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteMany

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('sessions', function (err, collection) {
      collection.deleteMany({ session: { $not: /.*passport.*/i }}, function(err, result){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
```

How do I limit this to only 100 documents? I tried

```
collection.deleteMany({ session: { $not: /.*passport.*/i }}, { limit: 100}, function(err, result){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
      });
```

because it looked like from the documents that may worked, but it didn't it deleted every document. How do I limit to only 100 documents?

Comment: Curious to know, why would you delete something with limit?

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta because the collection is so large, if I try and remove them all at once it times out. Just trying this out as a workaround

Comment: The deleteMany operation doesn't support a limit option. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22521865/16602311).

Comment: As others have described in the comments above, you cannot successfully issue a delete with a limit.  Instead, find N number the IDs of the records you want to delete, then issue the delete statement.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065615/how-to-delete-n-numbers-of-documents-in-mongodb

Comment: @barrypicker Thanks guys for the explanation, which is odd is that I tried that in the mongoshell and it didn't work. I suppose I will try with mongoose in a script.

Comment: @Anthony I delete content from my collection(>40mn) with query (on epoch). That's the only way I understand can limit delete :)

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to delete around 17 million items. Mongodb times out before I ever get it done. And it seems it does a find first before it does a delete, because none of them end up getting deleted.